# how to pattern match empty string in redis?

Tags: redis, pattern-matching, glob

In Redis, I have hash keys in the following format

```
keys {
  'img::opt': 'nameX',
  'img:*:opt': 'nameY',
  'img:#:opt': 'nameZ',
  'img:A:opt': 'nameN'
}
```

It is actually in the format of `'extension:owner:spec'`

I want to perform hscan based on owner which returns,

```
1. Everything except blank(will return 2nd, 3rd and 4th keys)
2. Only blank and star(*)(will return 1st and 2nd keys)
```

For first, I can use pattern as `'img:?*:opt'`. How to write a pattern which can be used for 2nd case.

I tried,

```
img:[^][*]:opt
img:[^|*]:opt
img:[*^]:opt
```

But none of them are working. Is it possible to pattern match empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis' glob-style pattern matching syntax doesn't support the not ('^') operator.

However, as you're looking for two specific keys, why not access them directly by simply doing:

```
HGET img:*:opt img::opt
```

Note: in Redis versions prior to 4, `HGET` needs to be replaced with [`HMGET`](https://redis.io/commands/hget)

Comment: Thanks, @Itamar for clarifying `^` is not supported in REDIS. Actually, there are different extensions possible. That's why I am using `hscan` so that I can do like `*:?*:opt`. Now it seems performing 2 hscans will be the only solution.